# joomla JViewHTML constructor and "Layout Path Not Found"

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

please read last line of question.

JviewHtml constructor contains following statement

```
$this->paths = isset($paths) ? $paths : $this->loadPaths();
```

i am setting the default path of myview using $path variable and passing it to constructor.

```
$paths = new SplPriorityQueue;
$paths->insert(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/views/' . $viewName . '/tmpl', 'normal');
```

in net beans debugger when i execute following statement of constructor $this->paths is not showing the value of $paths variable. although data type of both are splpriorityque

```
$this->paths = isset($paths) ? $paths : $this->loadPaths();
```

first statement of render is  render()

```
$path = $this->getPath($this->getLayout());
```

$path is returend with false value.

my main page shows error  "Layout Path Not Found". Any solutions to that problem

UPDATE:
LAST LINE
paths is splpriorityque 
            $abc=$paths;
            $this->paths=clone $paths

after these two statement $abc is showing correct value but $this->paths has missing or loastdata.in netbeans debugger

Comment: and i am using lendr sample joomla component as a reference. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i decided to delete this question because of very stupid mistake. but later i decided to remain as it is.

there was some setting problem or bug in netbeans, thats why it was unable to expand $this object member "splpriorityqueue".

```
$this->paths = isset($paths) ? $paths : $this->loadPaths();
```

above statement is perfectly correct.

and the error "layout path was not found" was beacause i named my tmpl folder as templ. which was causing 
    realpath() 
function in

```
JPath::find()
```

to not work properly.